# Is there any way to control the position or behaviour of the Internet Explorer required field prompt?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

We have a HTML form that has an `input` element with the `required` attribute set:

```
<input ui-date="dateOptions" id="ExpiryDate" name="expiryDate" 
       class="form-control hasDatepicker" required="">
```

When a user attempts to submit the form in Internet Explorer with the field empty, they get a prompt bubble noting `"This is a required field"`. However, the bubble appears in front of the calendar picker and cannot be dismissed by the user, making the calendar picker of limited use.

[image: Image of required field prompt obscuring the calendar picker]

Is there any way to control either the position of the prompt, or its behaviour, without removing the `required` attribute altogether?